# PHP mail() function goes to junk @ Outlook

Tags: php, email, header

When using the PHP mail() function, the email goes to the junk folder when I use the word "utvecklat" somewhere in my message. (it doesn't matter where)

But when I'm sending an email from Outlook to another Outlook-account (within the same mail server) it goes to the inbox.

Therefore, I think the problem is related to the mail headers.

**I'm using this PHP code:**

```
$subject='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
$emailTo="{$toEmail}";

$boundary = md5(date('U'));

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary={$boundary}\r\n";
$headers .= "From: \"{$fromName}\" <{$fromEmail}>\r\n";

$message = "This is a MIME encoded message."; 

$message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
$message .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
$message .= $message_tmp;

$message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "--";

mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f {$fromEmail}");
```

The email should be in HTML format. It doesn't matter if I use "utv**ecklat**", the email will go to the junk folder anyway.

So, what should I do to avoid the spam filter in Outlook? (must be something to do with my email headers, because mail from Outlook to Outlook within the same mailserver goes to the inbox.)

Thank you!

**UPDATE!**

Here you have a email sent from a outlook account to another. Can someone "convert" all this headers to a correct PHP mail() code? Thanks!

```
Return-Path: <example@domain.com>
Delivered-To: robin@example.com
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by example.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 9C67EC21B12
    for <robin@example.com>; Sat,  7 Apr 2012 17:58:14 +0200 (CEST)
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at example.example.com
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-Spam-Score: -2.47
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-2.47 required=6.31 tests=[ALL_TRUSTED=-1,
    BAYES_00=-1.9, HTML_MESSAGE=0.001, MIME_HTML_MOSTLY=0.428,
    TVD_SPACE_RATIO=0.001] autolearn=ham
Received: from example.example.com ([000.000.000.00])
    by localhost (example.example.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id HIlqLaU+2IIL for <robin@example.com>;
    Sat,  7 Apr 2012 17:58:11 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from Ciccidator (00-000-00-000-no56.tbcn.telia.com [00.00.00.000])
    by example.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 866F2C2059C
    for <robin@example.com>; Sat,  7 Apr 2012 17:58:11 +0200 (CEST)
From: "Example Sender" <example@domain.com>
To: <robin@example.com>
Subject: utvecklat
Date: Sat, 7 Apr 2012 17:58:01 +0200
Message-ID: <000001cd14d7$35d38070$a17a8150$@example.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0001_01CD14E7.F95C9E90"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 14.0
Thread-Index: Ac0U1zWPte9QsazETMuTKG6LDnf1fg==
Content-Language: sv
```

Comment: It's likely an issue with the SPAM filters, not with your sending program. It probably thinks you're sending email about penis enlargement (you're not, are you?). Going from Outlook to Outlook skips the filtering option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why are all mails sent via php's mail() go to spam box but not mails sent directly from the domain's account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032286/why-are-all-mails-sent-via-phps-mail-go-to-spam-box-but-not-mails-sent-direct)

Comment: Just to confirm: if you send a message from the PHP mail() function that includes the word "utvecklat" then it ends up in the junk folder, but if you send a message that is identical except without that word, it doesn't get junked?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the word. What language is it in and what does it mean in English?

Comment: It's Swedish, and in English it is "developed".

Comment: It would be useful to see the headers of the rejected mail in the same way. (That is, the headers of the delivered mail)

Comment: Why has an answer not been accepted?

Answer (score 2):

Omitting the junk mail covers a lot of ground, and can never be a 100% solution. Because email filtration might be different from one span engine to other.

- One the best way to confirm you always receive the mail is to the add the sender's email address on the recipient's address book.
- Another, you should confirm if the sender's email is not blacklisted on the internet.
- Always confirm you have sent the emails with correct header.
- Use Email Libraries like [PHP Mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

Fruther more: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2032448/295264) answer about MX entries.

Comment: For me the case was Outlook was sending any email from Yahoo to junk. Adding the yahoo.com domain to my safe sender list fixed the issue for me. There was nothing I had to do with my PHP form, aside from ensuring the headers were sedning the Reply-to and return-path variables.

Answer (score 0):

If your "From: " header contains a domain that does not match the domain of the server sending the mail, Outlook might bork.

Does Outlook accept emails from the script that do not contain this word?

Can you send this word to your Outlook inbox from, say, a gmail account or another "real" email client?

If the answer to both of these questions is "Yes"  then I would suggest taking a look at the headers in the accepted email and duplicating them *exactly*

Also, \r is not needed only \n iirc

Best of luck,

Comment: The domain is within the server. And yes, Outlook accepts other emails without this word. The email is in the inbox in Gmail, Hotmail etc.. So the problem is only in Outlook.

Comment: I have added the headers in the first topic now. If you have any solution on that question, please post! :)

Comment: hehe, example.com -- the local mail server is mis-configured.  You'll want  to change the local 'hostname' and re-configure the mail server accordingly. -- or you could spoof the from address...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) can solve your problem. Test it ...

Comment: Please use `$header .= "Reply-To: Some One <someone@mydomain.com>\r\n";` in your PHP scripts and test it again ... (Change it regarding to your information)